# Whats wrong with receiving Class name as user input in jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp, security

i have a web application
and receive class name as input in a JSON request in the below format

```
{ "type":"ClassName","id":"userid", and so on...
```

One security researcher informed it is a security issue even though necessary precautions are taken. But he doesn't provide any attack vector
i would like to know what are the risks involved with sending class name as a value

UPDATE: i have white listed possible classes using regex

Comment: why should you reveal more information to user

Comment: You did not give the full context, probably you are instantiating this class? One possible attack could be a denial of service if you use a class and parameters that crash the system.

Comment: What is done at server side with this information?

Comment: "receive class name as input" -- receive from where??

Comment: @Henry you are right but class names are white listed

Comment: @HotLicks it is a json request, users can edit it by intercepting request

Comment: Why do you send class name? Don't send class name. Use urlclassloader.

Comment: So there is no real reason to use "ClassName" rather than using "TheOptionThatWillUseClassName".  Both are equally safe in theory, but in practice someone is apt to get lazy and do `findClass(theJsonTypeValue)` when they shouldn't, so it seems wise to avoid that possibility.

Comment: "you are right but class names are white listed"...so why didn't you mention that in the question? Is this more a taunt question than a real question? Trying to get security people all fired up?

Comment: @HotLicks can you explain more

Comment: @jmj  can you please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139701/get-sqlexception-error-before-giving-the-user-input-in-jsp-page

Comment: @HotLicks  can you please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139701/get-sqlexception-error-before-giving-the-user-input-in-jsp-page

Answer (score 1):

The key problem is in the statement you gave:

> "even though necessary precautions are taken"

Honestly, you do not know that. You may think you do, but that is not necessarily the case. Constantly there are questions asking if a particular set up is secure. The answer is always no. Nothing is secure, but that shouldn't stop a programmer from trying to make something as secure as possible. New security vulnerabilities are found constantly on systems believed to be secure. It is impossible to account for all of these, so it is important in the fight for security to give no ground. I may not be able to provide you with a particular means to attack, but someone might. That someone might be the person that breaks your system with a new attack.

The main point is that you cannot know how someone may use a particular piece of information to attack your system. The vulnerability in this case is giving information that the user does not necessarily need. Security is not only about defending against attacks that people know about.

Comment: I can control which class is in input. and class should be instanced to complete some tasks. 
 i want a specific reason to change this behavior. the security researcher guy can't find it, thats why i asked here

Comment: @user3821631, Then why even have it in the input at all?

Comment: @developerwjk it was for bug fixing

Comment: @user3821631, the point of my answer is you shouldn't need a specific reason to change your behavior. There is a broad and overarching reason to not do this. Every piece of information given to a user and received from a user is a security vulnerability. From a security point of view, treat everything like it will break your system because it might. Thus, every time you give or receive information, you should ask if it is necessary to the function of the system. If the answer is no, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: @WilliamForcier So, do you mean that everything is a threat and you don't need to change something to overcome it?

Comment: @RomanC No, I'm saying everything is a threat, so you should change it unless you need it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no immediate issue with your implementation (assuming it is implemented properly).

You have to be absolutely sure that you validate the input, and that the input must be a valid one (member of a predefined set, or whitelist).

Once your value is validated properly, there is no serious difference between allowing a user to choose a classname from a set of possibilities and allowing a user to choose a identifier-string from a set of possibilities. In both cases, the program would use the input to decide what behavior to adopt.

The only real difference is about the information you place in the hands of a potential attacker. If you show me a selection of class names, then I pretty much know how you are handling this input, and therefore have a couple ideas on how I could exploit this information. I may be wrong, and your implementation might be secure... but still, it does not look secure, and borderline unprofessionnal (I hope you do not intend to sell this product).